# CS0535 C# does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, list

I have a little problem with writing Sort method, it should sort List `listaFarb` by `ObliczCene()` method.

Below is my code for class `Farba`, class `MagazynFarb`, class `FarbaSpecjalna` and Program with `Main()`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Farby
{
    class WrongPriceException : Exception
    {

    }
    class CenaMinimalnaException : Exception
    {

    }



    public enum Kolory { Biala, Zolta, Czerwona, Zielona, Niebieska }
    [Serializable]
    public class Farba : IComparable<MagazynFarb>
    {
        string producent;
        Kolory kolor;
        DateTime dataWaznosci;
        double dodatekDoCeny;
        static double cenaPodstawowa;

        public string Producent { get => producent; set => producent = value; }
        public Kolory Kolor { get => kolor; set => kolor = value; }
        public DateTime DataWaznosci { get => dataWaznosci; set => dataWaznosci = value; }
        public double DodatekDoCeny { get => dodatekDoCeny; set => dodatekDoCeny = value; }

        public Farba(string producent, Kolory kolor, string dataWaznosci)
        {
            if (producent.Length < 3)
                throw new Exception("Za krótka nazwa producenta");

            Random rnd = new Random();
            Producent = producent;
            Kolor = kolor;
            DateTime.TryParseExact(dataWaznosci, new[] { "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy/MM/dd", "MM/dd/yy", "dd-MM-yyyy" }, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out this.dataWaznosci);
            CenaPodstawowa = 20;
            DodatekDoCeny = rnd.Next(5, 10);
        }

        public static double CenaPodstawowa
        {

            get => cenaPodstawowa;
            set
            {
                cenaPodstawowa = value;
                if (value > 0)
                {
                    cenaPodstawowa = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new WrongPriceException();
                }
            }
        }
        public virtual double ObliczCene()
        {
            return CenaPodstawowa + DodatekDoCeny;
        }

        public virtual void SprawdzDateWaznosci()
        {
            int ldni = Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.Now - dataWaznosci).Days);
            double cena = ObliczCene();
            if (ldni > 0)
            {
                cena -= cena * (0.01 * ldni);
                if (cena <= CenaPodstawowa)
                {
                    throw new CenaMinimalnaException();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("gituwa");
            }
        }



        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append($"Producent: {producent}");
            sb.Append($", Kolor: {kolor}");
            sb.Append($", Data ważności: {dataWaznosci.ToShortDateString()}");
            sb.Append($", Cena: {ObliczCene():C}"); 
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public int CompareTo(MagazynFarb other) //NIE DZIAŁA
        {
            return ObliczCene().CompareTo(other);
        }
    }
}
```

Class `Farba` should implement interface `IComparable<Farba>` and sorts `listaFarb` by its price, `Cena` or `ObliczCene()`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PowtorkaFarba
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MagazynFarb
    {
        string nazwa;
        List<Farba> listaFarb;

        public MagazynFarb(string nazwa)
        {
            Nazwa = nazwa;
            listaFarb=new List<Farba>();
        }

        public string Nazwa { get => nazwa; set => nazwa = value; }
        internal List<Farba> ListaFarb { get => listaFarb; set => listaFarb = value; }

        public void DodajFarbe(Farba f)
        {
            listaFarb.Add(f);
        }

        public void UsunPrzedatowane(uint ldni)
        {
            //foreach (Farba f in listaFarb)
            //{
            //    if ((DateTime.Now - f.DataWaznosci).Days == ldni)
            //    {
            //        listaFarb.Remove(f);
            //    }
            //}

            listaFarb.RemoveAll(f => (DateTime.Now - f.DataWaznosci).Days == ldni);
        }

        public List<Farba> ZnajdzFarby(Kolory k)
        {
            return listaFarb.FindAll(f => f.Kolor == k);
        }

        public double WartoscMagazynu()
        {
            double sumawartosci = 0;
            foreach(Farba f in listaFarb)
            {
                sumawartosci += f.ObliczCene();
            }
            return sumawartosci;
        }

       public void Zapisz(string nazwaPliku)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(nazwaPliku, FileMode.Create))
            {
                bf.Serialize(fs, this);
            }
        }

        public object Odczytaj(string nazwaPliku)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(nazwaPliku,FileMode.Open))
            {
                return bf.Deserialize(fs);
            }
        }

        public void Sortuj()
        {
            listaFarb.Sort();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine($"Nazwa{Nazwa}");
            listaFarb.ForEach(f => sb.AppendLine(f.ToString()));
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PowtorkaFarba
{
    public enum Typy { lateksowa, winylowa}
    public class FarbaSpecjalna:Farba
    {
        double cenaSpecjalna;
        Typy typ;
        public FarbaSpecjalna(string producent, Kolory kolor, string dataWaznosci,Typy typ):base(producent,kolor,dataWaznosci) 
        {
            Typ = typ;
            Random r = new Random();
            CenaSpecjalna = Math.Round(r.NextDouble()*(5.00-3.00)+3.00, 2);
        }

        public double CenaSpecjalna { get => cenaSpecjalna; set => cenaSpecjalna = value; }
        internal Typy Typ { get => typ; set => typ = value; }

        public override double ObliczCene()
        {
            return base.ObliczCene()+CenaSpecjalna;
        }

        public override double SprawdzDateWaznosci()
        {
            int iloscDniPowyzejTerminu = (DateTime.Now - DataWaznosci).Days;
            double cena = ObliczCene() - ObliczCene() * 0.01 * iloscDniPowyzejTerminu;
            if ((DateTime.Now - DataWaznosci).Days > 0)
            {
                if (cena < CenaPodstawowa)
                {
                    throw new CenaMinimalnaException();
                }
                return cena;
            }
            else
            {
                return ObliczCene();
            }

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString()+$"Typ: {Typ}";
        }
    }
}
```

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace PowtorkaFarba
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    Farba f1 = new Farba("Dekoral", Kolory.Biala, "2020-05-09");
                    Farba f2 = new Farba("Dulux", Kolory.Niebieska, "2021-09-11");
                    Farba f3 = new Farba("Dulux", Kolory.Zielona, "2019-12-10");


                    //Console.WriteLine(f1);
                    //Console.WriteLine(f2);
                    //Console.WriteLine(f3);

                    //f1.SprawdzDateWaznosci();
                    //Console.WriteLine(f1);

                    //Console.WriteLine("Ilosc dni powyzej terminu: " + (DateTime.Now - f3.DataWaznosci).Days);

                    //Console.WriteLine("Oblicz cenę:" + f3.ObliczCene());
                    //Console.WriteLine(f3);

                    //FARBA SPECJALNA

                    FarbaSpecjalna fs1 = new FarbaSpecjalna("Dekoral", Kolory.Biala, "2019-12-09", Typy.lateksowa);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Oblicz cenę:" + fs1.ObliczCene());
                    //Console.WriteLine("Cena specjalna: " + fs1.CenaSpecjalna);
                    //Console.WriteLine(fs1);

                    MagazynFarb magazyn = new MagazynFarb("Magazyn 1");
                    magazyn.DodajFarbe(f1);
                    magazyn.DodajFarbe(f2);
                    magazyn.DodajFarbe(f3);
                    Console.WriteLine(magazyn);

                    //magazyn.UsunPrzedatowane(6);
                    //Console.WriteLine(magazyn);

                    foreach (Farba f in magazyn.ZnajdzFarby(Kolory.Niebieska))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ZNAJDZ FARBY\n" + f);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Wartość magazynu:\n" + magazyn.WartoscMagazynu());

                    Console.WriteLine("======================================================");

                    magazyn.Zapisz("magazyn.bin");
                    MagazynFarb magazyn2 = (MagazynFarb)magazyn.Odczytaj("magazyn.bin");
                    Console.WriteLine(magazyn2);

                }
                catch (WrongPriceException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Błędna cena");
                }
                catch(CenaMinimalnaException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cena minimalna - wyjątek");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, what is the question please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You've shown a lot of code, most of which is unrelated to the matter of sorting. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) from `Linq` for custom sorting, like:

```
    public void Sortuj()
    {
        listaFarb = listaFarb.OrderBy( farba => farba.ObliczCene()).ToList();
    }
```

Update: if usage of `List<T>.Sort()` is mandatory, you need to make `Farba` class to implement `IComparable<Farba>`, and compare `ObliczCene()` in the `CompareTo` method:

```
[Serializable]
public class Farba : IComparable<Farba>
{
    ...

    public int CompareTo(Farba other)
    {
        return ObliczCene().CompareTo(other.ObliczCene());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use IComparable<MagazynFarb> and add Sortuj() method to class MagazynFarb. It cannot be in different way :( and there is an error that element "Farba" doesn't implement component of the interface "IComparable,MagazynFarb>.CompareTo(MagazynFarb)"